# Failed to get session options?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I'm trying to switch the session store in Rails 3 by changing the 
config/application.rb as following:

```
config/application.rb 
#----------------------------------- 
memcache_options = { 
  :compression => true, 
  :debug => false, 
  :namespace => "xx-cache", 
  :readonly => false, 
  :urlencode => false 
} 
CACHE = MemCache.new(memcache_options) 
CACHE.servers = ['127.0.0.1:17898'] 
#check if CACHE is connected 
#puts CACHE 
config.action_dispatch.session = { 
  :session_key => '_xx_session', 
  :secret => 'xx', 
  :cache => CACHE, 
  :expires => 900 
} 
config.action_dispatch.session_store = :mem_cache_store 
#-----------------------------------
```

Memcache server is running. However, when run `rails s`, i got this 
message:

```
=> Booting WEBrick 
=> Rails 3.0.0.beta3 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000 
=> Call with -d to detach 
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server 
Exiting 
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.0.beta3/lib/ 
action_dispatch/middleware/session/mem_cache_store.rb:19:in 
`initialize': #<ActionDispatch::Session::MemCacheStore:0xa302950> 
unable to find server during initialization. (RuntimeError)
```

It seems the session options was not passed correctly. But i'm not 
sure what's wrong here cause I'm new to Rails.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not -entirely- sure, but I think you need to include "cached_model." Try adding

```
require 'cached_model' #(At the top)
```

Let me know if that worked.